# Rails 4 - destroy action deletes wrong record

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ajax, ruby-on-rails-3

I am doing an ajax request to rails passing in the data an id.

here is the ajax

```
function delete_availability(id) {
    var id = id;

    $.ajax({
      type: "DELETE",
      url: "/events/" + id,
      statusCode: {

        200: function() {
          //alert("200");
        },
        202: function() {
          //alert("202");
        }
      },
      success: function(data) {

        console.log('availability deleted');

      },
      error: function(xhr) {
        alert("The error code is: " + xhr.statusText);
      }
    });
  }
```

**my destroy action**

```
def destroy

    @event = Event.find_by(params[:id]);

    respond_to do |format|
      if @event.destroy
        format.json {
          render json: {}
        }
      end
    end
  end
```

**my event model has nothing in it**

```
class Event < ActiveRecord::Base

end
```

the problem is even though rails receives correct id, when it goes for destroying, it changes id and destroys the next one.

here is the **rails log:**

```
Processing by EventsController#destroy as */*
  Parameters: {"id"=>"66"}
  Event Load (0.1ms)  SELECT  "events".* FROM "events" WHERE (66) LIMIT 1
   (0.0ms)  begin transaction
  SQL (0.2ms)  DELETE FROM "events" WHERE "events"."id" = ?  [["id", 65]]
   (2.4ms)  commit transaction
Completed 200 OK in 6ms (Views: 0.1ms | ActiveRecord: 2.8ms)
```

anyone knows why?

Comment: Please post your event model.

Comment: it has nothing in it. just the class declaration,updating my post anyhow

Comment: Change `find_by` to `find`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should use `Event.find(params[:id])` or `Event.find_by(id: params[:id])`.

What happens with your code is that the SQL query finds every event - `WHERE (66)` is true for any record - and `find_by` takes the first record from the set, and it gets destroyed. The ID from the request doesn't matter.

Answer (score 1):

Why you use `find_by` its used when you want to use with different attribute to search use:

```
Event.find(params[:id])
```

OR use find_by_id if you want to not throw an Exception if record not find

```
Event.find_by_id(params[:id])
```

OR if you still want to use `find_by` you can use  which if no record is found it returns nil:

```
Event.find_by(id: params[:id])
```

and use `find_by!` to throuw an exception if no record found with this id:

```
 Event.find_by!(id: params[:id])
```